# [Angular2][NativeScript] template tag doesnt work in ListView

Tags: android, angular, listview, nativescript

Hi i have a problem with ListView in NativeScript using Angular2.

in my directive i have Array of Objects

```
export class Room {
constructor(
    public name: string,
    public tag: string
    ){ }
}

import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'rooms-list',
    templateUrl: "./template.html",
    providers: [RoomService],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class RoomsListComponent implements OnInit {

    public items: Array<Room> = [];

    listLoaded = false;

    load() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                this.items.push(
                    new Room("room " + i, "tag " + i)
                );

            }
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.load();
    }
    onTap(name){
        console.log('taped: '+name);
    }
}
```

in my template i use ListView

```
<ListView [items]="items" id="roomsList">
    <template let-item="item">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label [text]='"[" + item.tag +"] " + item.name'></Label> 
        </StackLayout>
    </template>
</ListView>
```

but it looks like template tag doesnt exist, list contain only 
`[object Object]` elements.

Comment: Your code looks fine? What version of nativescript do you use?

Comment: Yes what version are you using, if you are using the RC (meaning Angular 4) the `<template>` has been changed to `<ng-template>`, similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43074761/3801632

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov with ng-template its still doesnt work.
Im using nativescript 2.5

Answer (score 0):

When using the `moduleId: module.id` in a `@Component` you need to give only the name of the `templateUrl` without any directories. Using the moduleId makes it so that any Url is looked in the current directory so you no longer need to specific the absolute path. Simply do the following:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'rooms-list',
    templateUrl: "template.html",
    providers: [ RoomService ],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

More information can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451917/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls) thread, you can also take a look at the official NAtiveScript ng examples [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/modules25/app/ui-category/listview/creating-listview).

Comment: Can you try a simpler binding expression like `[text]="item.tag"` just to make sure that the items of the ListView are actually populated. Also can you edit your post to include the source of the `Room` object, maybe there is something there.

Comment: i fixed it by importing NativeScriptModule from nativescript-angular/nativescript.module in my ngModule. before that i import this in component

Answer (score 0):

The below works in NativeScript/Angular 5, should also in Angular 2 I think. Change:

```
<StackLayout>
```

to:

```
<StackLayout (tap)="onTap(item)">
```

and:

```
onTap(name){
    console.log('taped: '+name);
}
```

to:

```
onTap(item){
    console.dir(item); // So item is a Room object
}
```

Angular 5 would need ng-template instead of template as well.